# Multi threaded FFTW 3.1.2 on a shared memory computer

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran, shared-memory, fftw

I use [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) 3.1.2 with Fortran to perform real to complex and complex to real FFTs. It works perfectly on one thread.

Unfortunately I have some problems when I use the multi-threaded FFTW
on a 32 CPU shared memory computer. I have two plans,
one for 9 real to complex FFT and one for 9 complex to real FFT (size
of each real field: 512*512). I use Fortran and I compile (using [`ifort`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Fortran_Compiler)) my
code linking to the following libraries:

```
-lfftw3f_threads -lfftw3f -lm -lguide -lpthread -mp
```

The program seems to compile correctly and the function `sfftw_init_threads` returns a non-zero integer value, usually 65527.

However, even though the program runs perfectly, it is slower with 2
or more threads than with one. A `top` command shows weird CPU load
larger than 100% (and much more larger than n_threads*100). An `htop`
command shows that one processor (let's say number 1) is working at a
100% load on the program, while ALL the other processors, including
number 1, are working on this very same program, at a 0% load, 0% memory and 0 TIME.

If anybody has any idea of what's going on here... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it could be a synchronisation problem. You can get this type of behaviour if all threads except one are locked out e.g. by a semaphore to a library call.

How are you calling the planner? Are all your function calls correctly synchronised? Are you creating the plans in a single thread or on all threads? I assume you've read the notes on [thread safety](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Thread-safety.html) in the FFTW docs... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unless your FFTs are pretty large, the automatic multithreading in FFTW is unlikely to be a win speed wise.  The synchronization overhead inside the library can dominate the computation being done.  You should profile different sizes and see where the break even point is.